# Getting Errors with my SQL Parser function in Python

Tags: python, sql, parsing, ply

I am trying to write simple function in python that parses through the following query:

```
sql_statement = 'SELECT EMPLOYEE.EMPNO, POSITION FROM EMPLOYEE E, JOBHISTORY J WHERE E.EMPNO = J.EMPNO AND STARTDATE <= ENDDATE'
```

When I implement my parser function on my SQL query I keep getting the following error:

```
Syntax error at token IDENTIFIER
Syntax error at token IDENTIFIER
Syntax error at token COMMA
Syntax error at token IDENTIFIER
Syntax error at token IDENTIFIER
Syntax error at token IDENTIFIER
Syntax error at token IDENTIFIER
Syntax error at token COMMA
Syntax error at token IDENTIFIER
Syntax error at token IDENTIFIER
Syntax error at token IDENTIFIER
Syntax error at token IDENTIFIER
Syntax error at token EQUAL
Syntax error at token IDENTIFIER
Syntax error at token IDENTIFIER
Syntax error at token IDENTIFIER
Syntax error at token LESS_EQUAL
Syntax error at token IDENTIFIER
Syntax error at EOF
None
```

Below is my parser function written in Python

```
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc

#define the lexer
tokens = (
    'SELECT',
    'FROM',
    'WHERE',
    'IDENTIFIER',
    'LITERAL',
    'COMMA',
    'EQUAL',
    'AND',
    'LESS_EQUAL',
 )

t_SELECT = r'SELECT'
t_FROM = r'FROM'
t_WHERE = r'WHERE'
t_IDENTIFIER = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_.]*'
t_LITERAL = r'\d+'
t_COMMA = r','
t_EQUAL = r'='
t_AND = r'AND'
t_LESS_EQUAL = r'<='
t_ignore = ' '

def p_statement_select(p):
    'statement : SELECT select_list FROM from_clause where_clause'
    # print('SELECT list detected')
    print('SELECT statement detected')
    
def p_select_list(p):
    '''select_list : IDENTIFIER COMMA select_list
                    | IDENTIFIER'''
    print('SELECT list detected')
    
def p_from_clause(p):
    'from_clause : IDENTIFIER COMMA IDENTIFIER'
    print('FROM clause detected')
    
def p_where_clause(p):
    'where_clause : condition'
    print('WHERE clause detected')
              
                    
def p_condition(p):
    '''condition : IDENTIFIER
                | LITERAL
                | condition AND condition
                | condition EQUAL condition
                | condition LESS_EQUAL condition'''
    print('Condition detected')
    
def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s' at index %d" % (t.value[0], t.lexpos))
    t.lexer.skip(1)
    
    
def p_error(p):
    if p:
        print("Syntax error at token", p.type)
        # just discard the token and tell the parser its okay
        parser.errok()
    else: 
        print("Syntax error at EOF")
        
#Define the lexer
lexer = lex.lex()

#Define the parser
parser = yacc.yacc()
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong I have changed my functions where_clause and p_condition several times but I keep getting this error.

The final output of the code should be something like this:

```
('SELECT', [('COLUMN', 'EMPLOYEE.EMPNO'), ('COLUMN', 'POSITION')], [('TABLE', 'EMPLOYEE'), ('TABLE', 'JOBHISTORY')], [('CONDITION', 'E.EMPNO', '<=', 'J.EMPNO'), ('CONDITION', 'STARTDATE', '<=', 'ENDDATE'), ('CONDITION', 'SALARY', '<=', 3000)])
```

Answer (score 1):

There a couple of issues I could identify, these are the changes required:

```
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc

tokens = (
    'SELECT',
    'FROM',
    'WHERE',
    'IDENTIFIER',
    'LITERAL',
    'COMMA',
    'EQUAL',
    'AND',
    'LESS_EQUAL',
)

t_SELECT = r'SELECT'
t_FROM = r'FROM'
t_WHERE = r'WHERE'
t_IDENTIFIER = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_.]*'
t_LITERAL = r'\d+'
t_COMMA = r','
t_EQUAL = r'='
t_AND = r'AND'
t_LESS_EQUAL = r'<='
t_ignore = ' \t\n'

def p_statement_select(p):
    '''statement : SELECT select_list FROM from_clause where_clause
                 | SELECT select_list FROM from_clause'''
    p[0] = ('SELECT', p[2], p[4], p[5] if len(p) > 5 else None)

def p_select_list(p):
    '''select_list : IDENTIFIER COMMA select_list
                   | IDENTIFIER'''
    if len(p) == 2:
        p[0] = [('COLUMN', p[1])]
    else:
        p[0] = [('COLUMN', p[1])] + p[3]

def p_from_clause(p):
    '''from_clause : IDENTIFIER from_clause
                   | IDENTIFIER'''
    if len(p) == 2:
        p[0] = [('TABLE', p[1])]
    else:
        p[0] = [('TABLE', p[1])] + p[2]

def p_where_clause(p):
    '''where_clause : WHERE condition_list
                    | WHERE condition'''
    p[0] = p[2]

def p_condition_list(p):
    '''condition_list : condition AND condition_list
                      | condition'''
    if len(p) == 2:
        p[0] = [p[1]]
    else:
        p[0] = [p[1]] + p[3]

def p_condition(p):
    '''condition : IDENTIFIER EQUAL IDENTIFIER
                 | IDENTIFIER LESS_EQUAL IDENTIFIER
                 | IDENTIFIER EQUAL LITERAL'''
    p[0] = ('CONDITION', p[1], p[2], p[3])

def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s' at index %d" % (t.value[0], t.lexpos))
    t.lexer.skip(1)

def p_error(p):
    if p:
        print("Syntax error at token", p.type)
        parser.errok()
    else:
        print("Syntax error at EOF")

lexer = lex.lex()
parser = yacc.yacc()

sql_statement = 'SELECT EMPLOYEE.EMPNO, POSITION FROM EMPLOYEE E, JOBHISTORY J WHERE E.EMPNO = J.EMPNO AND STARTDATE <= ENDDATE'
result = parser.parse(sql_statement)
print(result)
```

Added a failsafe on `p_statement_select(p):` in case there is no `WHERE` clause

Also instead of printing the result `p_select_list` and `p_from_clause` were modified to return a list of tuples
These changes allow the parser to build a list of conditions with their respective operators.